# Java Swing - How to position cursor inside JTextField from PlainDocument

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

My java swing application has a JTextFied. I am usind a PlainDocument subclass for input manipulation.

```
public class MaskDecimalDocument extends PlainDocument {

   public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {

      //manipulation input code

      super.insertString(0, manipulatedText, a);

   }

}
```

The user insert a character, the insertString method handle the haracter and inserts it in the text. Next  manipulation, the cursor is positioned at the end of text. How do I position the cursor at original place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using a `DocumentFilter` since it is the newer API for handling changes to a `Document`. The concept is the same but the class is more reusable since it can be added to any `Document`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for more information.

> How do I position the cursor at original place ?

When you create your custom `DocumentFilter` class you would need to pass in the text field that uses the `Document` as a parameter and save this text field as an instance variable of your class.

Then the logic in the `replaceSelection(...)` method would be something like:

```
int caretPosition = textField.getCaretPosition();
super.replaceSelection(...);
textField.setCaretPosition( caretPosition );
```

Note you may need to place the `setCaretPosition(...)` method in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to make sure the code is executed after the default processing for setting the caret position.

Answer (score 1):

Controlling the caret position is not a Document’s job.  You should [set a NavigationFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setNavigationFilter-javax.swing.text.NavigationFilter-) which ignores all changes to the caret position:

```
textField.setNavigationFilter(new NavigationFilter() {
    @Override
    public void setDot(FilterBypass bypass,
                       int position,
                       Position.Bias bias) {
        // Deliberately empty
    }

    @Override
    public void moveDot(FilterBypass bypass,
                        int position,
                        Position.Bias bias) {
        // Deliberately empty
    }

    @Override
    public int getNextVisualPositionFrom(JTextComponent component,
                                         int position,
                                         Position.Bias bias,
                                         int direction,
                                         Position.Bias[] newBias) {
        return position;
    }
});
```